# React Router Displaying only Blank Page - No data Showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I am new to React. It's My First Program with React - Router When I Am Using React-Router I Don't get any data displaying on the window. It only Shows Blank Page.

My code -
profile.js

```
import React from 'react'
 function Profile()
 { return ( <div>
   <h1>profile</h1> 
   </div> ) }

export default Profile
```

about.js file

```
import React from 'react'

function About() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>about</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

App.js

```
import About from './Container/about'
import Profile from './Container/profile'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
 return ( 
<div className="App"> 
<BrowserRouter> 
<Route element={About} path='/about' /> 
<Route element={Profile } path='/profile' /> 
</BrowserRouter> 
</div> 
); 
}

export default App;
```

If anybody Know any Solution Please Reply

I Checked some websites for results but I Don't get any solution from them. I watched some Youtube videos. but they code the same as mine and they got results but I didn't.

Comment: It will show the blank page because you have no route for "/". By going to "/about" and "/profile" you will be able to see your components

Comment: @AsadAshraf I am checking '/about' and '/profile' and it also have blank pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use **older version** import **Switch** from **react-router-dom**

```
import About from "./Container/about";
import Profile from "./Container/profile";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={About} path="/about" />
          <Route component={Profile} path="/profile" />
       </Switch>
     </Router>
 </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

if you using **latest version** ..import **Routes** from **react-router-dom**
App.js
import Routes

```
    import About from './Container/about'
    import Profile from './Container/profile'
    import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
    function App() {
     return ( 
      <Router> 
        <div className="App"> 
         <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/about' element={<About />}  /> 
          <Route exact path='/profile' element={<Profile /> }  /> 
         </Routes>
        </div> 
      </Router> 
      ); 
      }
    
     export default App;
```

Comment: how to import "Routes route "?. there is nothing named 'Routes Route'. It shows error

Comment: import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: There are two different Routes and Route... import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) from `react-router-dom` which renders the route exclusively.

Your code would be like this.

```
import About from "./Container/about";
import Profile from "./Container/profile";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={About} path="/about" />
          <Route component={Profile} path="/profile" />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Check this  [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/recursing-hoover-8qew3d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) where react-router-dom is implemented with dynamic params as well as components.

Comment: It Shows 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: I think you are using v6. I've used v5 in the testing code. Will share the updated sandbox in some time. You can check the official documentation. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: Thank You. I Am Using v6. Documentation helped me 